# back button navigation doesn't work for iOS 11 in phonegap app

Tags: javascript, ios, jquery-mobile, ios11, phonegap

I'm having a phonegap app running latest version of cli-6.5.0. The issue that I'm facing is ,the back button is not working, only in iOS. Its working perfectly in Android.

I'm having jqueryMobile's 'data-rel="back"' on top of the html page and when the back-button in my app is hit,the line "window.history.go(-1)" gets hit and takes us to prev page.

But the issue here,when I've outputted the "window.history.length" in the alert box in both Android and Apple. The length was showing perfectly in Android, but for some reason, in Apple the length will always be "2". Due to this reason, when I press back button in the app, it will take me either to the first page or gets stuck at the current page.

This issue has started recently when I've updated the phonegap version from cli-5.4.1 to cli-6.5.0 , and with the iOS 11 release, the issue started crawling. I believe that the tie-up between these two isn't working, because it used to work before.

Any help would be great!

Thank you

Comment: Im having the same issue in ionic 1. If it happen of you solve it please post the solution here.

Comment: I didn't get a solution yet for this. So I tracked history in the stack by myself in the code.